# What if you try to hide an already hidden component?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I think it's a very basic thing but I'm still not sure what happens.

For example I have a SeekBar, when I start to change its value I want a TextView to be hidden, but what happens if it is already hidden and I try to hide it?, Will that line of code be skipped or will it be executed?

For example, is it more advisable to do this ?:

```
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if (textView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
```

Or is it better to do this?

```
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

I know that the result of the above codes is the same, but I want to do a good practice

Answer (score 1):

If they both do the same thing I would go for the  one with no if statement because I personally like having cleaner looking code. But from how small of a function it is go for the one you feel is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to care about if is visible or not, `setVisibility` method do that by itself, so if it's already hiden, nothing happens. If you are curious about how `View` handle this, you can check the source code :) `setVibility` invoke `setFlags` and there is where the magic happens.

Source code:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/view/View.java

So you should use:

```
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```